# How to make schematic density curves in r?

Tags: r, density-plot

I'm trying to make schematic density curves, just to represent idea. I tried the following code:

This isn't based on any actual data, I just need a nice image.

```
green1 <- rnorm(n=10000, mean=6, sd = .5)
green2 <- rnorm(n=10000, mean=18, sd = .5)
green3 <- rnorm(n=10000, mean=30, sd = .5)
green <- c(green1, green2, green3)

red1 <- rnorm(n=10000, mean=-2, sd = .01)
red2 <- rnorm(n=10000, mean=2, sd = .01)
red3 <- rnorm(n=10000, mean=10, sd = .01)
red4 <- rnorm(n=10000, mean=14, sd = .01)
red5 <- rnorm(n=10000, mean=22, sd = .01)
red6 <- rnorm(n=10000, mean=26, sd = .01)

red <- c(red1, red2, red3, red4, red5, red6)

plot(density(green), col= 'blue', xlim=c(-5,35))
lines(density(red), col= 'red')
```

But the red curves in between the peaks aren't always touching the 0 line, and changing the sd to something smaller doesn't make a difference. Can anyone help please?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with your sd.  It is the way that the bandwidth is computed for the `density` function.  Because the range of the data is so wide, `density` uses a wide band which makes two adjacent distributions overlap. You need to reduce the bandwidth by using the `adjust` parameter. Here is your code with only minor changes. You can even make the red sd be bigger and this will work.

```
plot(density(green), col= 'blue', xlim=c(-5,35), ylim=c(0,0.14))
lines(density(red, adjust=0.5), col= 'red')
```

[image: Density curves with reduced bandwidth]

Comment: Thank you! This is brilliant. Can I just ask for one more thing please - I'd like the blue ones to be taller than the red ones. Can that be adjusted as well? Thanks so much again!

Comment: Yes.  Make all of the `sd=0.1` for the red points.  Then use `plot(density(green, adjust=0.6), col= 'blue', xlim=c(-5,35)); 
lines(density(red, adjust=0.5), col= 'red')`